# Replace value with NA in next row on the same column if condition in another 3 columns are accepted

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements

I need to replace data in the next row of the same column with NA if condition on 3 column are same with the previous row. How to write the code of this condition?

for example I have sample data like this

```
store camp  var    value
 a     1     ax     200
 b     2     bx     100
 a     1     ax     200
 b     2     bx     100
 c     2     cx     100
 a     1     ax     200
 c     2     cx     100
```

to be like this

```
store camp  var    value
 a     1     ax     200
 b     2     bx     100
 a     1     ax     NA
 b     2     bx     NA
 c     2     cx     100
 a     1     ax     NA
 c     2     cx     NA
```

is there anyway to do this? thanx in advance

Comment: Do you mean any previous column, or the row immediately above

Comment: i mean any previous column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use duplicated - this matches what you have

```
 x <- data.frame( 
 store = c( "a","b","a","b","c","a","c"),
 camp = c(1,2,1,2,2,1,2),
 var = c( "ax","bx","ax","bx","cx","ax","cx"),
 value = c( 200,100,200,100,100,200,10))

 x[ duplicated( x[ , c( "store","camp","var")]) ,"value"] <- NA
```

Comment: is the condition of duplicated can be written more than 3 column?

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto, sure put however many columns you want in the vector  c( "store","camp","var").  You can do logical, character or numeric to select the columns